# Unhandled Exception: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, sql-server-2017, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have hosted service in .netcore which runs several functions which execute SQL queries every second. While running app for a while it crashes, I know the problem it is exhausting all the connection pools and I'm not handling the connections properly. I know I need to open and close the connection.

> dbcontext Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

The issue I'm facing is I'm using `DBContext` which automatically fetches and open the database connection for me and I don't explicitly have to tell to open the connection but then how can I close the connection? for each `Scope`?

```
public class DBChangeService : DelegatingHandler, IHostedService
        {
            private Timer _timer;
            public SqlDependencyEx _sqlDependency;
            private readonly IHubContext<SignalServer> _hubcontext;
            private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

            public DBChangeService(IHubContext<SignalServer> hubcontext, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
            {
                _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
                _hubcontext = hubcontext;
            }

            public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                _timer = new Timer(Heartbeat, null, 0, 1000);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            public async void Heartbeat(object state)
            {
                await _hubcontext.Clients.All.SendAsync("SBSystemBrodcasting", SBSystemApps());
                await _hubcontext.Clients.All.SendAsync("SBUserBrodcasting", SBNonSystemApps());
            }

            public List<SomeModel> SBSystemApps()
            {
                using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PlatformStatusContexts>();
                    var result = _DBcontext.SomeModels.FromSql((
                                @"SELECT 
                    a.app_guid as AppGuid,
                    a.name as AppName,
                    a.state as AppState,
                    a.created_at as AppCreatedAt,
                    a.updated_at as AppUpdatedAt,
                    a.foundation as AppFoundation,

                    s.name as SpaceName,
                    o.name as OrgName
                FROM
                    apps as a
                INNER JOIN
                    spaces as s ON a.space_guid = s.space_guid
                INNER JOIN
                    organizations as o ON s.org_guid = o.org_guid
                where s.name = 'system' and o.name = 'system' and a.foundation = 2")).ToList();

                    return result;
                }
            }

            public List<SomeModel> SBNonSystemApps()
            {
                using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PlatformStatusContexts>();

                    var result = _DBcontext.SomeModels.FromSql((
                                @"SELECT 
                    a.app_guid as AppGuid,
                    a.name as AppName,
                    a.state as AppState,
                    a.created_at as AppCreatedAt,
                    a.updated_at as AppUpdatedAt,
                    a.foundation as AppFoundation,

                    s.name as SpaceName,
                    o.name as OrgName
                FROM
                    apps as a
                INNER JOIN
                    spaces as s ON a.space_guid = s.space_guid
                INNER JOIN
                    organizations as o ON s.org_guid = o.org_guid
                where s.name != 'system' and o.name != 'system' and a.foundation = 2")).ToList();
                    return result;
                }
            }


            public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                //Timer does not have a stop. 
                _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
```

Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<PCFStatusContexts>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Connection String:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=address,port;Database=dbname;User Id=uname;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

Update:

DBContext:

```
public partial class PlatformStatusContexts : DbContext
{
    public PlatformStatusContexts()
    {
    }

    public PlatformStatusContexts(DbContextOptions<PlatformStatusContexts> options): base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Apps> Apps { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Organizations> Organizations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Spaces> Spaces { get; set; }
    public DbQuery<SomeModel> SomeModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //model builder for each table


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `AddDbContextPool`? That should manage the connections better.

Comment: I have looked into it but I was not able to implement it correctly, I will try again now.

Comment: There's not anything to implement. You just literally switch out `AddDbContext` with `AddDbContextPool`. That's it.

Comment: I did that it is giving me an error `The DbContext of type 'PlatformStatusContexts' cannot be pooled because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions.`

Comment: Alright. Well, you shouldn't have any constructors other than that one, so what do you have additional, and why do you have it?

Comment: As you can see in the code above there are only ` _scopeFactory = scopeFactory; and 
            _hubcontext = hubcontext;`  in the constructor and I need those below in my code.

Comment: *On your context*. The error is complaining about additional constructors on your context. You should only have a single public constructor on your context, and that single public constructor should *only* take `DbContextOptions` as a dependency.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I have updated question with my DBConext

Comment: Get rid of the parameterless constructor.

Comment: WOW, thats working thanks, Chris :)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to use using with context as the below

```
 using(var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PlatformStatusContexts>())
 {
      var result = _DBcontext.SomeModels.FromSql((
                                @"SELECT 
                    a.app_guid as AppGuid,
                    a.name as AppName,
                    a.state as AppState,
                    a.created_at as AppCreatedAt,
                    a.updated_at as AppUpdatedAt,
                    a.foundation as AppFoundation,

                    s.name as SpaceName,
                    o.name as OrgName
                FROM
                    apps as a
                INNER JOIN
                    spaces as s ON a.space_guid = s.space_guid
                INNER JOIN
                    organizations as o ON s.org_guid = o.org_guid
                where s.name = 'system' and o.name = 'system' and a.foundation = 2")).ToList();

                    return result;

 }
```

Comment: No. It's created within a scope and will be disposed by the service collection when the scope goes away (the end of its `using`).